# TypeScript equivalent of Java method references

Tags: java, typescript, lambda, scope, method-reference

I'm sort of new to TypeScript, I know Java quite well though. There, whenever a functional interface needs to be satisfied, it's most commonly done using lambda expressions (`->`) or method references (`::`).

Lambda expressions seem to be equivalent between the two languages (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there a way to make use of method references?

When the goal is to achieve this:

```
  this.entryService.getEntries()
    .subscribe(entries => this.listUpdateService.send(entries));
```

Is there a way to use a function reference? The following way of doing it appears to be errorous, because `send` isn't executed in the scope of `this.listUpdateService`. (BTW, which scope is it executed in?)

```
  this.entryService.getEntries()
    .subscribe(this.listUpdateService.send);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the scope is not `this.listUpdateService`.

If you want to stick the correct scope, you normally use `bind`.

```js
this.entryService.getEntries()
  .subscribe(this.listUpdateService.send.bind(this.listUpdateService));
```

[Here is an example playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQgUwDsATACgEp0sdrgB7AiWkPAOhFoHMSAXACwEsIZANxVsAXwySMoSDACCBWnzwAnZHMrUw0ALzQATKOoc83AKIFuq-nggkAZgQBc0cnoB80AG61%20RCkxqaidyYxxJaToGbmhaACMAKwBGPWgCPAB3OCQUexEZeghYhMSDNIzsxWVeNQ0oMIxChiZWdi4AIgR6mDwADzxgAFdufgIODrIMUuSWfGJyZsZmNk4SDuqVVWhZVH7BkbGJqdKDFlMLKxs7Ehm5wgDRaOW2tY2lLZ286H3h0fHoJl%20HxoPExkRJtMkmcLpZrLZ7Hd5kQWGCFjMyCIgA)